# Qual a diferença entre -= e =-?

Tags: java, operadores

Em `java` e outras linguagens  Já vi em alguns projetos coisas do tipo:

`saldo -= 100` e as vezes `saldo =- 100` mas nunca consegui entender a diferença entre esses dois tipos, isso se conter alguma diferença.

Afinal, existe alguma diferença entre realizar uma operação com `-=` e `=-` ?

Comment: Tem certeza que já viu `saldo =- 100` em algum lugar? Basicamente está atribuindo -100 à variável. Não vejo isso como possível considerando o mesmo contexto do `saldo -= 100`.

Comment: Sem contar que a duvida é a mesma, as respostas respondem para ambos os casos.

Comment: @Articuno obrigado!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, aonde o exemplo dado interfere na resposta? Creio eu que  não afetou no entendimento, tanto que o pessoal já deram algumas respostas concretas.

Comment: Sim, era essa a dúvida. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelos comentários.

Comment: resposta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/why-dont-javas-compound-assignment-operators-require-casting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`saldo -= 100` é a mesma coisa que `saldo = saldo - 100`.

`saldo =- 100` está atribuindo `-100` à variável `saldo`. Fica mais claro de visualizar assim:

`saldo = -100`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 9):

O operador `-=` em java é utilizado quando queremos atribuir o valor de uma variável a subtração de um segundo valor ao atual valor desta variável.

Veja este exemplo:

```
int a -= b;
```

é o mesmo que fazer:

```
int a = a - b;
```

Já `=-` não é um operador, é simplesmente uma atribuição dando um sinal negativo ao valor a ser atribuido a direita.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 9):

Olá!  Sei que sua dúvida foi sanada pelos amigos. Somente irei compartilhar mais uma explicação sobre, pois é a que eu geralmente passo quando alguém me pergunta o mesmo. Então vai como "um complemento" das respostas acima.

Veja:

```
saldo = 500;
saldo -= 100;

System.out.println(saldo);
```

Janela de saída imprime:

```
run:
400
```

Nesta próxima lógica, a primeira atribuição no valor de *500*, não vale mais para variável *saldo* e o dono da conta ainda ficou com saldo negativo.

```
saldo = 500;
saldo =- 100;

System.out.println(saldo);
```

Janela de saída imprime:

```
run:
-100
```

Lembrando que o dono da conta também ficará com saldo negativo, se for feito assim:

```
saldo = 500;
saldo -= 600;

System.out.println(saldo);
```

Janela de saída imprime:

```
run:
-100
```

Comment: Obrigado, @CarlosHeuberger! Lembrando que o `run:...` , não é parte do código. É a parte que programa imprime para a janela Saída (juntamente com outros resultados do script de compilação).

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você entendeu o conceito de incremento e decremento errado, veja bem, no primeiro caso você, realmente está decrementando a variável saldo em -100, no entanto; no segundo caso você está atribuindo à variável o valor -100.

Veja o exemplo abaixo de um decremento:

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int saldo = 14000;
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            saldo -= 100; //Aqui tem um decremento
            System.out.println("saldo : "+ saldo);
        }
    }
}
```

Seu resultado é:

```
saldo : 13900
saldo : 13800
saldo : 13700
saldo : 13600
saldo : 13500
```

Agora perceba se você fizer o inverso, que é colocar o sinal - depois da sinal de atribuição =, ficando `sando =- 100`

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int saldo = 14000;
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            saldo =- 100; //Aqui tem uma atribuição, isto é, mesma coisa que saldo = -100;
            System.out.println("saldo : "+ saldo);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado, ficou -100 em tudo, pois a cada loop a variável saldo foi atribuída o valor de -100:

```
saldo : -100
saldo : -100
saldo : -100
saldo : -100
saldo : -100
```